# A simple python list program getting Index error

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sorry for asking this question. This is simple python program

```
odd = lambda x : bool(x % 2)
numbers = [n for n in range(10)]
print numbers
for i in range(len(numbers)):
    if numbers[i]%2!=0:
        del numbers[i]
    print numbers
```

I am getting error while running this program
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    if numbers[i]%2!=0:
IndexError: list index out of range`

I tried many thing but nothing is working, Can any one help me

Comment: it is because you are deleting the elements in loop rather save it in other list

Comment: @VigneshKalai is there any way to delete the elements

Comment: why do you need the odd lambda function ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove items from a list while iterating in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 odd = lambda x : bool(x % 2)
    numbers = [n for n in range(10)]
    print numbers
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        try:
            if numbers[i]%2!=0:
               del numbers[i]
                print numbers
        except IndexError:
            pass
```

Answer (score 3):

**Notes:**

If you really `NEED TO DELETE THE LIST WHEN LOOPING` you could loop the list in reverse and delete the elements it will not stop the iteration since it will delete the element in normal direction (left --> right) and the loop is in opposite direction (right-->left)

**Code:**

```
odd = lambda x : bool(x % 2)
numbers = [n for n in range(10)]
print numbers
for i in numbers[::-1]:
    print i
    if i%2!=0:
        del numbers[numbers.index(i)]
print numbers
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Or to be even more simple how about a `list comprehension and your lambda function`

**Code1:**

```
[num for num in numbers if not odd(num)]
```

**Output1:**

```
 [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Comment: @khelwood what mistake ?

Comment: You are using `i` as the items in the list, not the index, so `pop(i)` is not suitable.

Answer (score 2):

```
b = range(10)
a = [i for i in b if not i%2]

print a
```

Comment: Why not just `a = [i for i in b if i%2==0]`